# Consider the straight lines in xy plane $ax+by+c=0, bx+cy+a=0, cx+ay+b=0$. These lines intersect at point if and only if $a+b+c=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the straight lines in xy plane $ax+by+c=0, bx+cy+a=0, cx+ay+b=0$. These lines intersect at point if and only if $a+b+c=0$

These are planes through z-axis.My doubt is how can these 3 planes thru z-axis intersect in a point??? It should be a line right? pls englighten me here...

Also linear combination of these equations gives $(x+y+1)(a+b+c) =0$

For given condition to be true i.e., If $a+b+c=0$ means $(x+y+1) \neq 0$. But how to show this?

Comment: I would advise giving an actual title.

Comment: pls suggest me title. I will edit. I posted Qn directly

Comment: What $z$-axis? This is a 2-d problem.

Comment: Why can’t both $a+b+c=0$ and $x+y+1=0$ hold?

Comment: The lines of form $ax+by=0$ represent planes through z axis. equations of lines you give are not of this form.